# Add additional disks through metadata on Goocle Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, packer

I want to build a Google Cloud image using Packer, but can't seem to find a way for packer to add additional disks. This is required as want a persistent disk for application to store data on it.

Is it something that can be done through startup_script or any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick glance at the GCE API documentation it looks like images only can contain one device, the boot device.